# Escaping symbols in cron

Tags: oracle, bash, cron, heredoc

I have the following script (it connects to oracle database, looking for applied arclogs and deletes it):

```
ARCLOGS=$(/oracle/base11202/11202/bin/sqlplus -s /  as sysdba <<EOF
set head off
set verify off
set feedback off
select name from v$archived_log where applied = 'YES' and first_time > sysdate - 1 order by sequence#;
exit;
EOF)

echo "${ARCLOGS}" | while read arc
do
  if [[ -e $arc ]] 
  then
    rm -f $arc
  fi
done
```

It works fine when i start it by myself. But the idea is to start it with cron. Cron gives errors when trying to start this script:

> ```
> Your "cron" job executed on test on Mon Nov 14 15:17:00 2011
> if [ -e /arclogs/arcs.sh ]; then sh -x /arclogs/arcs.sh; fi 
>
>
> produced the following output:
>
> + + /oracle/base11202/bin/sqlplus -s / as sysdba
> + 0<<
> set head off
> set verify off
> set feedback off
> select name from v$archived_log where applied = "YES" and first_time > sysdate - 1 order by sequence#;
> exit;
> ARCLOGS=select name from v$archived_log where applied = "YES" and first_time > sysdate - 1 order by sequence#
>                                                 *
> ERROR at line 1:
> ORA-00904: "YES": invalid identifier
> + read arc
> + echo select name from v$archived_log where applied = "YES" and first_time > sysdate - 1 order by sequence#
>                                                 *
> ERROR at line 1:
> ORA-00904: "YES": invalid identifier
> + [[ -e select name from v$archived_log where applied = "YES" and first_time > sysdate - 1 order by sequence# ]]
> + read arc
> + [[ -e * ]]
> + read arc
> + [[ -e ERROR at line 1: ]]
> + read arc
> + [[ -e ORA-00904: "YES": invalid identifier ]]
> + read arc
> ```

Looks like the problem with escaping symbols. But i have no idea what i have to escape.

Btw, the scripts works with cron when i split it in two pieces:

arcs.sh:

```
ARCLOGS=$(/oracle/base11202/bin/sqlplus -s /  as sysdba <<EOF
set head off
set verify off
set feedback off
select name from v$archived_log where applied = 'YES' and first_time > sysdate - 1 order by sequence#;
exit;
EOF)

echo "${ARCLOGS}" | while read arc
do
  if [[ -e $arc ]] 
  then
    rm -f $arc
  fi
done
```

and arcs.sql:

```
connect / as sysdba
set head off
set verify off
set feedback off
select name from v$archived_log where applied = 'YES' and first_time > sysdate - 1 order by sequence#;
exit;
```

But i want to have it in one piece. Can someone, please, help?

Comment: Show us the line you are putting in your crontab.

Comment: It's in the second line of cron output `if [ -e /arclogs/arcs.sh ]; then sh -x /arclogs/arcs.sh; fi`

Comment: Try changing `<<EOF` to `<<'EOF'`. That should prevent the shell from interpreting anything in the here document.

Comment: See edit 2 in my answer. Try putting the 'YES' inside double quotes: "'YES'".

Comment: Changing `<<EOF` to `<<'EOF'` doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just taking a shot in the dark. Try calling /bin/bash explicity from your cron line. Cron executes with sh by default.

Comment: Do you mean change `if [ -e /arclogs/arcs.sh ]; then sh -x /arclogs/arcs.sh; fi` to `if [ -e /arclogs/arcs.sh ]; then /bin/bash /arclogs/arcs.sh; fi` ?

Comment: I'm beginning to think that this is the answer - that your `/bin/sh` is interpreting `$(...)` oddly. Does it work if you change it to use backticks? Anyway, I would take out the variable completely and just do `sqlplus <<EOF | while read ...`

Comment: @stee1rat No, on the actual cron line. have the * * * * * part for the time specification. After that put "/bin/bash /arclogs/arcs.sh."

Comment: I should try your answer at first, 'cause it helps! Thanks everyone for trying to help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping the single quotes with a backslash:

```
select name from v$archived_log where applied = \'YES\' and first_time > sysdate - 1 order by sequence#;
```

The quotes are clearly being eaten by the shell, and Oracle is trying to interpret a bare string YES as an identifier rather than the string constant.

EDIT:

Is the cron task run under your ID?

EDIT 2:

Try this:

```
select name from v$archived_log where applied = "'YES'" and first_time > sysdate - 1 order by sequence#;
```

Comment: Nope, the problem stays. Except it shows `\'YES\'` in the error message. Btw, why does it show `"YES"` instead of `'YES'` without escaping it (error message in my original post)?

Comment: Because Oracle thinks you've passed it an identifier named YES. Oracle puts the identifier in double quotes which is confusing here. It's been a while since I've used any *nix shell stuff so I don't recall how you need to escape the single quotes, but I'll think about it today.

Comment: No, the error message is from the shell; the output from Oracle is an error message which is echoed back from the `read`.

Comment: The output from Oracle is an error message generated because the quotes were not passed as part of the SELECT statement, and the value YES was handed to Oracle, which Oracle interprets as an identifier, which it is not, hence the ORA-00904.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't help.. now it's says that "'YES'" is invalid identifier.. So i think there's no solution except extra .sql file.